# How to close c# webbrowser print preview dialog

Tags: c#

This is my code in sample:

```
WebBrowser web1 = new WebBrowser();  
...  
void showPrintPreviewDialog(){
     web1.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
}

void closePrintPreviewDialog(){
...
}
```

Could you tell me how to close print preview dialog? I tried to with dispose method but it's not work, the dialog is still there. I'm code with .net 3.5

Comment: Click the close button..

Answer (score 0):

Close PrintButton from code is not easy. Maybe you can use [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) from WIN API or you can create custom form dialog as window (Window as Close method) Here is small example:

```
class CustomPrintDialog : PrintPreviewDialog
{

}
```